# SQL: Check for 'value' is not null returns TRUE when 'value' is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008, and when I perform a left join to a table where the outer table does not have any records then I am seeing weird behavior from my where clause.  If I do a check for a value from my outer table being 'not null' it *sometimes* returns true.

```
select *
from foo f left join bar b on b.id=f.id
where f.id=@id and (f.status = 1 or b.Price is not null)
```

When my `f.status = 0` and `b.Price` does not exist (or, appears as null in the select) this query selects records where `f.status = 0` and `b.Price is null`, even though (FALSE OR FALSE) should be FALSE.

If I just perform this query, it works as expected and anything without a record in 'bar' does not get selected.

```
select *
from foo f left join bar b on b.id=f.id
where f.id=@id and b.Price is not null
```

Having `b.Price is not null` as part of an `or` operation seems to be causing issue for some reason.  What could be wrong with this query?  I run the same query with similar data on a SQL Server 2012 machine and do not see this issue, could it be related the the version of SQL Server I am using?

Answer (score 1):

These two formulations are *not* the same, as you have discovered.

In the first query, `price` can be `NULL` for two reasons:

- There is no match from the `left join`.
- There is a match and `b.Price` is null

I highly recommend the second approach, putting the condition in the `on` clause.  However, if you do use the first one, make the comparison to a column used in the `join`:

```
where f.id = @id and (f.status = 1 or b.id is not null)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try an `OUTER APPLY` like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo f
OUTER APPLY (
SELECT *
FROM bar b
WHERE f.id = b.id
    AND (
        f.STATUS = 1
        OR b.Price IS NOT NULL
        ) b
)
WHERE f.id = @id
```

And I also suggest using the columns instead of *, bad practice. The Outer Apply is sort of like a left join and in this case it will filter all the data from the bar table and bring you back only the data you need.

Answer (score 1):

Would a CASE statement work?

IE

SELECT

(etc etc code)

CASE WHEN b.Price is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [MyBooleanCheck]

FROM (etc etc code)